# What is the best way to sort a sequence in Python?

Tags: python, csv, conditional-statements

I am trying to sort the table based on certain conditions that need to happen in a row.
Simplified version of a table:

```
Number  Time
   1    23
   2    45
   3    67
   4    23
   5    11
   6    45
   7    123
   8    34
```

...

I need to check if time was <40 5 times in a row. Like I need to check rows 1-5, then 2-6 etc... And then print and save to a file the first and last time. Like, if the condition is met for rows 2-6 I will need to print time for Number 2 and Number 6. The checking should stop after condition has been met. No need to  check other rows.  I implemented a counter with two temp variables to check for 3 items in a row so far. It works fine. But, if I want to check for the condition that happened 30 times in a row, I can not just create 30 temp variables manually. What is the best way to achieve that? I guess I will just need some kind of a loop. Thanks!

Here is part of my code:

```
reader = csv.reader(open(filename))
counter, temp1, temp2, numrow = 0, 0, 0, 0

for row in reader:
    numrow+=1
    if numrow <5:
        col0, col1, col4, col5, col6, col23, col24, col25 = float(row[0]),
            float(row[1]), float(row[4]), float(row[5]),float(row[6]), 
            float(row[23]), float(row[24]), float(row[25])
        if col1 <= 40:
            list1=(col1, col3, col4, col5, col6, col23, col24, col25)
            counter += 1
            if counter == 3:
                print("Cell# %s" %filename[-10:-5])
                print LAYOUT.format(*headers_short)
                print LAYOUT.format(*temp1)
                print LAYOUT.format(*temp2)
                print LAYOUT.format(*list1)
                print ""

            elif counter == 1:
                temp1=list1

            elif counter == 2:
                temp2=list1

        else:
            counter = 0
```

I implemented solution suggested by Bakuriu and it seems to be working. But what will be the best way to combine numerous testing? Like I need to check for several conditions. Lets say:
v

- efficiency for less than 40 in 10 cycles in a row,
- capacity for less than 40 in 5 cycles in row
- time for less than 40 for 25 cycles in a row
- and some others...

Right now I just open csv.reader for every testing and run the function. I guess it is not the most efficient way, although it works. Sorry, I am just a complete noob.

```
csvfiles = glob.glob('processed_data/*.stat')
for filename in csvfiles: 

    flag=[]
    flag.append(filename[-12:-5])
    reader = csv.reader(open(filename))
    for a, row_group in enumerate(row_grouper(reader,10)):
        if all(float(row[1]) < 40 for row in row_group):         
            str1= "Efficiency is less than 40 in cycles "+ str(a+1)+'-'+str(a+10)  #i is the index of the first row in the group.
            flag.append(str1)
            break #stop processing other rows.

    reader = csv.reader(open(filename))    
    for b, row_group in enumerate(row_grouper(reader,5)):
        if all(float(row[3]) < 40 for row in row_group):
            str1= "Capacity is less than 40 minutes in cycles "+ str(a+1)+'-'+str(a+5)
            flag.append(str1)
            break #stop processing other rows.

    reader = csv.reader(open(filename))    
    for b, row_group in enumerate(row_grouper(reader,25)):
        if all(float(row[3]) < 40 for row in row_group):
            str1= "Time is less than < 40 in cycles "+ str(a+1)+'-'+str(a+25)
            flag.append(str1)
            break #stop processing other rows.

   if len(flag)>1:

       for i in flag:
            print i
        print '\n'
```

Comment: That's an unconventional meaning of 'sort' you have there...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't really need to sort your data, just keep track of whether the condition you're looking for has occurred in the last *N* rows of data. Fixed-size [`collections.deque`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.deque)s are good for this sort of thing.

```
import csv
from collections import deque
filename = 'table.csv'
GROUP_SIZE = 5
THRESHOLD = 40
cond_deque = deque(maxlen=GROUP_SIZE)

with open(filename) as datafile:
    reader = csv.reader(datafile) # assume delimiter=','
    reader.next() # skip header row
    for linenum, row in enumerate(reader, start=1):  # process rows of file
        col0, col1, col4, col5, col6, col23, col24, col25 = (
            float(row[i]) for i in (0, 1, 4, 5, 6, 23, 24, 25))
        cond_deque.append(col1 < THRESHOLD)
        if cond_deque.count(True) == GROUP_SIZE:
            print 'lines {}-{} had {} consecutive rows with col1 < {}'.format(
                linenum-GROUP_SIZE+1, linenum, GROUP_SIZE, THRESHOLD)
            break  # found, so stop looking
```

Comment: Great answers guys. Both methods looks good. I just wish I was more proficient in Python, so I could at least read the script. Being so new to Python is hard, and trying to complete a project for management with so little knowledge is even harder. Thanks a again. I will try to implement your suggestions in my scripting.

Comment: Here I also get an error:
ValueError: invalid literal for float(): 1,00000005.04428203596,0000041078.87327

Comment: Looks like you might need a `delimiter=','` on the `csv.reader()` call (actually that's the default, I used tab because of how your simplified version of the table appeared). You can also see what has been read by printing `row` to see the data being returned.

Comment: Sorry, my bet. Did't pay attention to delimiter. In my case it was jut a comma. Worked great. The only thing is that it prints 4 rows instead of 5. I guess I should make group size 6 then, sine Python does not include the last item in the list. Thanks again!

Comment: Not sure what you mean about outputting only 4 rows instead of 5 because the only output is one line when and if it finds 5 consecutive rows where the condition is True.

Comment: Nevermind. I just put print row, and it printed just 4, but I dont need to print it anyway. Your script worked fine with one file, but when I tried to run on several .csv files it didnt work. It was saying like: "Lines 1-5 had consecutinve rows with <40" for the first file. But then for some reason it was outputting something like   "Lines -5 - 1 had consecutive rows with <40" or similar to that. Sorry, I am not by my PC right now. Something was happening after the first run.

Comment: Note that this reads rows in *two* places: It first uses `row = reader.next()` to read `GROUP_SIZE-1` (4) of them in to preload the `deque`, then reads the remainder in the `for row in reader:` loop.

Comment: You built a beautiful script and I am trying to implement it, but I have hard time to run it on several conditions (like if I need to check if condition happened in several columns) and on several files in folder.

Comment: @Pasha: To do more than one condition/column at once you would need to have a separate deque for each one. Then all of them will need to be updated (`deque.append`), or updated and checked (`deque.count`) each iteration of both loops. I see you've asked a question already that looks like it's about how to do this -- I'll look more closely at it and see about applying this solution to it (time permitting).

Comment: Yes, I created a new question just today. I actually managed to implement your code and it works awesome. But I just created a copy of your code for every new condition. Bruit and force approach but it works just fine and its actually quite fast. I am sure it can be done in more efficient way. Right now the code looks huge!

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to sort the data at all. A simple solution might be:

```
def row_grouper(reader):
    iterrows = iter(reader)
    current = [next(iterrows) for _ in range(5)]
    for next_row in iterrows:
        yield current
        current.pop(0)
        current.append(next_row)


reader = csv.reader(open(filename))

for i, row_group in enumerate(row_grouper(reader)):
    if all(float(row[1]) < 40 for row in row_group):
        print i, i+5  #i is the index of the first row in the group.
        break #stop processing other rows.
```

The `row_grouper` function is a generator that yields 5-element lists of consecutive rows. Every time it removes the first row of the group and adds the new row at the end.

---

Instead of a plain `list` you can use a `deque` and replace the `pop(0)` in `row_grouper` with a `popleft()` call which is more efficient, although this doesn't matter much if the list has only 5 elements.

Alternatively you can use martineau suggestion and use the `maxlen` keyword argument and avoid `pop`ing. This is about twice as fast as using a deque's popleft, which is about twice as fast as using the `list`'s `pop(0)`.

---

**Edit:** To check more than one condition you can modify use more than one `row_grouper` and use `itertools.tee` to obtain copies of the iterables.

For example:

```
import itertools as it

def check_condition(group, row_index, limit, found):
    if group is None or found:
        return False
    return all(float(row[row_index]) < limit for row in group)


f_iter, s_iter, t_iter = it.tee(iter(reader), 3)

groups = row_grouper(f_iter, 10), row_grouper(s_iter, 5), row_grouper(t_iter, 25)

found_first = found_second = found_third = False

for index, (first, second, third) in enumerate(it.izip_longest(*groups)):
    if check_condition(first, 1, 40, found_first):
        #stuff
        found_first = True
    if check_condition(second, 3, 40, found_second):
        #stuff
        found_second = True
    if check_condition(third, 3, 40, found_third): 
        # stuff
        found_third = True
    if found_first and found_second and found_third:
        #stop the code if we matched all the conditions once.
        break
```

The first part simply imports `itertools`(and assigns an "alias" `it` to avoid typing `itertools` every time).

I've defined the `check_condition` function, since the conditions are getting more complicated and you don't want to repeat them over and over. As you can see the last line of `check_condition` is the same as the condition before: it checks if the current "row group" verifies the property. Since we plan to iterate over the file only once, and we cannot stop the loop when only one condition is met(since we'd miss the other conditions) we must use some flag that tells us if the condition on (e.g.) time was met before or not. As you can see in the `for` loop, we `break` out of the loop when all the conditions are met.

Now, the line:

```
f_iter, s_iter, t_iter = it.tee(iter(reader), 3)
```

Creates an iterable over the rows of `reader` and makes 3 copies of it.
This means that the loop:

```
for row in f_iter:
    print(row)
```

Will print all the rows of the file, just like doing `for row in reader`.
Note however that `itertools.tee` allows us to obtain copies of the rows *without* reading the file more than once.

Afterwards, we must pass these rows to the `row_grouper` in order to verify the conditions:

```
groups = row_grouper(f_iter, 10), row_grouper(s_iter, 5), row_grouper(t_iter, 25)
```

Finally we have to loop over the "row groups". To do this simultaneously we use `itertools.izip_longest` (renamed to `itertools.zip_longest` (without `i`) in python3).
It works just like `zip`, creating pairs of elements (e.g. `zip([1, 2, 3], ["a", "b", "c"]) -> [(1, "a"), (2, "b"), (3, "c")]`). The difference is that `izip_longest` *pads* the shorter iterables with `None`s. This assures that we check the conditions on all the possible groups(and that's also why `check_condition` has to check if `group` is `None`).

To obtain the current row index we wrap everything in `enumerate`, just like before.
Inside the `for` the code is pretty simple: you check the conditions using `check_condition` and, if the condition is met you do what you have to do *and* you have to set the flag for that condition(so that in the following loops the condition will always be `False`).

(Note: I must say I did not test the code. I'll test it when I have a bit of time, anyway I hope I gave you some ideas. And check out the documentation for `itertools`).

Comment: Could've used [deque](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.deque) with efficient pop/appends on both sides.

Comment: @kroolik We are talking about a list of fixed (really small)size. The time is constant anyway. (If you `timeit` it you'll see using a normal `list` is less than 2x slower, which isn't that bad considering the shifts that `pop(0)` has to do).

Comment: I tried this method but the script throws me an error with "Invalid Syntax" in current = [next(iterrows) for_ in range(5)]

Comment: @Pasha I forgot one space between `for` and the `_`. Fixed.

Comment: OK, got it. There was also another error. Just a typo in "row_groupuer". I am getting some output now. The function seems to be working. I also updated my post with more questions about implementing your function. If you could help further I d appreciate it. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks again. A bit complicated for such a noob but i will try to process it with my limited knowledge. One other thing: I need to output the result if any or several conditions have been met, not exactly all of them.