# How to check for multiple concurrent events in several rows for several columns at the same time in Python?

Tags: python, csv, conditional-statements

I am trying to sort huge load of .CSV files produced by our equipment but got stock with sorting part. Every file consists of 30+ columns and can have infinite number of rows. What I need to implement is how to check for events that happen in multiple columns for several rows concurrently. Like, for example I will need to check if any of the results:

- in column "Test_Res_1" had values less than 12 for for 15 consecutive testes
- in column "Test_Res_2" had values less than 5 for for 10 consecutive testes
- in column "Test_Div" had values less than 15 for for 20 consecutive testes
- in column "Test_time" had values less than 60 for for 10 consecutive testes
- ..............some other condition for several consecutive tests....

Then if any or several conditions have been met I will just write the name of that file into .txt file. I implemented the code suggested by a user from this forum and the script works fine. But I just copy a block that performs checking every time I want to check for another condition. I am sure there is a better way to implement that code and reduce that huge scrip I currently have.

Here is an example of the file:
[image]

I tried several suggestions I found on that forum but none of them worked. Some of them worked with one condition, but I need to check for several conditions as I d mentioned. I know how to open the files and save them to .txt if the condition has been meet, but I just cant figure out how to check for multiple conditions in multiple columns and rows. Checking for one row is easy, but checking for several of them gives me big trouble.

```
import os, os.path, zipfile, csv, datetime
import smtplib, os
f = open("test.txt", "w")
flagtotal=[]
path="datafiles/"  # insert the path to the directory of interest
dirList=os.listdir(path)
for filename in dirList:
    if filename.endswith((".csv")):       
        file=os.path.splitext(filename)
        reader = csv.reader(open(filename))
```

> ```
>         # I GOT STOCK HERE!!!! Although the code seems to work just fine. I create a completely  new instance for reader every time I want to add new condition. reader.next() # skip header row
>     GROUP_SIZE = 5
>     THRESHOLD = 0.5
>     cond_deque = deque(maxlen=GROUP_SIZE) # *maxlen* requires Python version 2.6+        
>     linenum = 0
>     while len(cond_deque) < GROUP_SIZE-1:
>         try:
>             row = reader.next()
>             linenum += 1
>             col0, col1, col4, col5, col6, col23, col24, col25 = (
>                 float(row[i]) for i in (0, 1, 4, 5, 6, 23, 24, 25))
>             cond_deque.append(col1 < THRESHOLD)
>         except StopIteration:
>             print 'less that {} rows of data in file'.format(GROUP_SIZE)
>             break
>     # then process any remaining lines
>     for row in reader:
>         col0, col1, col4, col5, col6, col23, col24, col25 = (
>             float(row[i]) for i in (0, 1, 4, 5, 6, 23, 24, 25))
>         linenum += 1
>         cond_deque.append(col1 < THRESHOLD)
>         if cond_deque.count(True) == GROUP_SIZE:
>             str1 = 'Condition 1 in cycles {}-{} had {} consecutive cycles  < {}'.format(
>                 linenum-GROUP_SIZE+1, linenum, GROUP_SIZE, THRESHOLD)
>             #print str1
>             flag.append(str1)
>             break  # stop looking
>
>     #checking for the second condition
>     reader = csv.reader(open('processed_data/'+filename))
>     reader.next()        
>     GROUP_SIZE = 2
>     THRESHOLD = 20
>     cond_deque = deque(maxlen=GROUP_SIZE) # *maxlen* requires Python version 2.6+        
>     linenum = 0
>     while len(cond_deque) < GROUP_SIZE-1:
>         try:
>             row = reader.next()
>             linenum += 1
>             col0, col1, col4, col5, col6, col23, col24, col25 = (
>                 float(row[i]) for i in (0, 1, 4, 5, 6, 23, 24, 25))
>             cond_deque.append(col1 < THRESHOLD)
>         except StopIteration:
>             #print 'less that {} rows of data in file'.format(GROUP_SIZE)
>             break
>     # then process any remaining lines
>     for row in reader:
>         col0, col1, col4, col5, col6, col23, col24, col25 = (
>             float(row[i]) for i in (0, 1, 4, 5, 6, 23, 24, 25))
>         linenum += 1
>         cond_deque.append(col5 < THRESHOLD/60)
>         if cond_deque.count(True) == GROUP_SIZE:
>             str1 = 'Condition 2 {}-{} had {} consecutive cycles  < {} minutes'.format(
>                 linenum-GROUP_SIZE+1, linenum, GROUP_SIZE, THRESHOLD)
>             #print str1
>             flag.append(str1)
>             break  # stop looking
> ```

```
today = datetime.date.today()
datestring='Date of testing: '+today.strftime('%m/%d/%Y')
if len(flagtotal)>0:
    flagtotal.insert(0,datestring)
    flagtotal.insert(1,'The following files met the criteria.\n--------------------------------------------')
    f.write("\n".join(map(lambda x: str(x), flagtotal)))
f.close()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the following shows how to do what you want. It's based on using the `collections.deque` class. It's basically a generalized version of the logic in my answer to your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17559058/355230). This was done by encapsulating all the pieces of data and related processing from the criterion into a application-centric class.

The result requires a fair amount of code, but is more compact and likely faster than it would have been the approach you were attempting. It only reads each file once and checks whether any of a variable number of conditions are met during that single pass.

```
import csv
from collections import deque
import datetime
from glob import iglob
import os

class Criterion(object):
    """ represents one of the criteria to be checked.
        in_a_row is the number of consecutive rows in which the expression,
        given as a string, evaluated to True """
    def __init__(self, in_a_row, expression):
        self.in_a_row = in_a_row
        self.expression = expression
        self.bytecode = compile(expression, '<string>', 'eval')
        self.deque = deque(maxlen=in_a_row)
    def eval_and_check(self, local_vars):
        """ evaluate expression in context of local variables, append result
            to deque, and return whether 'in_a_row' criterion was satisfied """
        self.deque.append(eval(self.bytecode, globals(), local_vars))
        return self.deque.count(True) == self.in_a_row
    def reset(self):
        self.deque.clear()
    def format_match(self, filename, linenum):
        return 'lines {}-{} in {} had {} consecutive rows with "{}"'.format(
            linenum-self.in_a_row+1, linenum, filename, self.in_a_row,
            self.expression)

criteria = [Criterion(5, 'Test_Res_2 < 40'),
            Criterion(3, '13 <= Test_Res_4 <= 15'), ]
flagtotal = []
datapath = "datafiles"  # directory path to location of csv files

for filename in iglob(os.path.join(datapath, '*.csv')):
    with open(filename) as csvfile:
        reader = csv.reader(csvfile, skipinitialspace=True)
        reader.next() # skip over initial fieldnames row
        for criterion in criteria:  # initialize all before processing file
            criterion.reset()
        condition_satisfied = False
        for linenum, row in enumerate(reader, start=1):
            # define local vars for use in criterion expression evaluation
            (Test_num, Test_Res_1, Test_Res_2, Test_Res_3, Test_Res_4, 
             Test_div, Test_time) = [int(row[0])] + map(float, row[1:])
            for criterion in criteria:
                if criterion.eval_and_check(locals()):
                    #print criterion.format_match(filename, linenum)
                    flagtotal.append(os.path.basename(filename))
                    condition_satisfied = True
                    break  # quit criterion checking for this row
            if condition_satisfied:
                break  # quit processing rows of this csv file

with open('test.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write('Date of testing: {}\n'.format(
            datetime.date.today().strftime('%m/%d/%Y')) +
            'The following files met the criteria:\n'
            '-------------------------------------\n')
    if flagtotal:
        print('\n'.join(flagtotal))
        f.write('\n'.join(flagtotal) + '\n')
    else:
        print('no files met the criteria')
        f.write('no files met the criteria\n')
```

Comment: Thanks again Martineau. This is a piece of beautiful code you produced. I wish I had more knowledge of Python and OOP in particular to be able to digest that code less painfully. I will try to implement your suggestion. Thanks  again!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the `csv` module, but let's assume you can get a dictionary of columns. Then you can do this to find consecutive entries in one column:

```
import itertools

# in column "Test_Res_1" had values less than 12 for for 15 consecutive tests
col = reader["Test_Res_1"] # get the column as a list

# Find a count of the consecutive values < 12
consec_lt_12 = [len(list(cnt)) for val,cnt in itertools.groupby(col, lambda x: x < 12) if val]

# Check if the maximum is >= 15
if (max(consec_lt_12) >= 15):
   # ok! found it
```

If you can get that to work, then just repeat it for whatever columns you want and whatever values, and chain them together however you like (e.g. do you need to find values in column A **and** column B, or column A **or** column B, etc.)